# Setting form target via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

The below form `.submit()` opens a new window, and nothing appears in the iframe, despite the `form target='my-form-target`. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q81Lgmmf/1

```
createAndSubmitForm();

function createAndSubmitForm() {
  var formBody = '<form action="//fiddle.jshell.net"><input value="123"></form>';
  var formContainer = document.createElement('div');
  var formTarget = document.createElement('iframe');


  document.body.appendChild(formContainer);
  document.body.appendChild(formTarget);
  formTarget.name = 'my-form-target';
  formContainer.innerHTML = formBody;

  // setting form target to the iframe
  // this sets the action, but iframe does not receive anything on submit
  formContainer.children[0].target = formTarget.name;

  // submit comes in a new window as if target were _blank
  formContainer.children[0].submit();
}
```

I need to set the target of a newly-created form to a newly-created iframe via JS.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions again. Turns out this error occurs when appending the new form/iframe to the document before setting up the target relationship. Im not clear on the exact order but doing the appends last does the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/q81Lgmmf/3/

```
  formTarget.name = 'my-form-target';
  form.target = 'my-form-target';

  document.body.appendChild(formTarget);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
```